# Adding a node to beginning of a list in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I'm learning linked list basics via Sedgewick's *Algorithms* and came across adding nodes to the beginning of a linked list. I've noticed they're redefining the "first node" using the code below:

```
Node firstNode = new Node();
Node secondNode = new Node();
Node thirdNode = new Node();

//create 3 initial nodes
firstNode.item = "to";
secondNode.item = "be";
thirdNode.item = "or";

//set order of nodes
firstNode.next = secondNode;
secondNode.next = thirdNode;

//add new node to beginning
Node oldFirstNode = firstNode;

//recreate first node
firstNode = new Node();

firstNode.item = "not";
firstNode.next = oldFirstNode;
```

Why do we not do: `Node firstNode = new Node();`?
Not understanding why it's instead `firstNode = new Node();`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Both lines are present in the code you posted.

Answer (score 3):

You couldn't have

```
Node firstNode = new Node();
```

later on in the code - because that would be trying to declare a new local variable with the same name as an existing one. (You can have a local variable with the same name as an instance field or a static field, but you can't have two local variables with the same name in scope at the same time.) Instead, this line:

```
firstNode = new Node();
```

assigns a new value to the *existing* local variable.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you assign to `firstNode` is when you define it:

```
Node firstNode = new Node();
```

Once it's defined, you already have a variable named `firstNode`, so you mustn't redefine it, just assign a new value to it - in this case, a newly created `Node`:

```
firstNode = new Node();
```